# Timer: setTimeout and function call

Tags: javascript

```
function tick() {
    seconds_lapsed++; // Break point.
}

function countdown() {   

    while(!stopped || !is_paused()){
        setTimeout(tick, 1000); // 1 second.
        show_counter();
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why the interpreter doesn't stop at the breakpoint? The while loop works, hava a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is async/await. That while loop with setTimeout inside it is going to be called MANY times before it's gonna stop. That loop is making too many timeouts. Put a console.log('asd') in the while loop to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is a "busy" loop, i.e. it keeps the JavaScript engine busy, so it will not process anything that is waiting in one of its event/job queues. This means that the user interface does not get updated, no input can be processed, and events produced by `setTimeout` are not consumed. In this example, `tick` can only get executed if the currently running code *finishes*. So the `while` loop must end first.

You should let `tick` execute, and only then check the condition:

```js
var stopped = true;
var seconds_lapsed = 0;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    stopped = !stopped;
    seconds_lapsed = 0;
    this.textContent = stopped ? "Start" : "Stop";
    if (!stopped) countdown();
});

function show_counter() {
    document.querySelector("span").textContent = seconds_lapsed;
}

function is_paused() {
    return document.querySelector("input").checked;
}

function tick() {
    seconds_lapsed++;
}

function countdown() {   
    show_counter();
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (stopped) return; // stop the loop
        if (!is_paused()) tick();
        countdown(); // <--- this is the "loop"
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
Seconds elapsed: <span>0</span><br>
<input type="checkbox">Paused<br>
<button>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following example might help you accomplish what you are after. Distinguish between [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Basically the docs say:

> **setTimeout** executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

> **setInterval** repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

So if you use setInterval you don't need a while loop inside because it is already called "repeatedly"

```js
var counter = $('#counter');

var stopped = false;
var seconds_lapsed=0;
var myInterval;

function tick() {
    if(stopped) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        show_counter('FINISHED');
        return;
    }
    show_counter(seconds_lapsed++);
}

function show_counter(message){ 
    counter.html(message);
}

function countdown() {   
    myInterval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

function endCountdown(timeout) {
    let timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        stopped = true;
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }, timeout);
}

countdown(); // start the countdown

endCountdown(5000); // ends the countdown after 5000 ms => 5sec
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">counter</div>
```